# Not implemented Javascript error in IE7 when binding function

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I get the javascript error

```
SCRIPT16385: Not implemented
```

When i run the following piece of code..

```
 $j('img[id="edit_destination"]').bind('click',function(){
           document.getElementById("edit_destination").onclick = editPRINum(this);

});
```

editPRINum is a function in the same javascript. I googled the problem and looks like i have to declare in case it is a variable. However i am using this to bind a function. What should i be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try this

```
$j('img#edit_destination').bind('click',editPRINum);
```

In your callback function (editPRINum), `this` will be a reference to the `img` element.

PS: What is $j? a shortcut to jQuery?

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks :)
P.S. I use $j to ensure no conflicts in jquery.